# Javascript email validation does not work

Tags: javascript, email-validation

What is wrong with my code? I can't find the solution.

```
var re = "/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/";

var email= document.getElementById("email").value;

if (re.test(email) == false) {  
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

The double quotes caused the problem, thank you!
I cant vote up because of my reputation :-(

Comment: why so complicated? [`see here`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+validation+javascript&submit=search)

Comment: You tell *us* what's wrong. Do you get an error? Does it not validate correctly? Does it pass all input, or does it not pass any valid emails, or does it give false positives/negatives?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Holy moley! That's a complex validation you have there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suresh suggested, you should remove the quotes (") around your regex string.
So your first line should be:

```
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

I produced a working example below:

```
<script>
function test()
{
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]    {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var email= "test@somedomain.com";

  if (re.test(email) == false) {  
    alert("invalid email address");
    return;
  }
  alert("valid address");
}
</script>
<button onclick="test()">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets try this once which is working smart for me

```
  function IsEmail(email) {
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                return regex.test(email);
             }

if(!IsEmail(mailString)){
                $("#somediv").text(" Email should be valid ");
                return false;
                }
```

Comment: People - the question is "What is wrong with **my** code". It's *not* "how to validate email addresses".

Comment: @jim bamboo ..remove the "" to your regex string .